# Set group owner using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I use this command:

Set-SPOSiteGroup -Site htt.....com -Identity newgroup -Owner newgroup2

(newgroup is a Sharepoint group, newgroup2 is another sharepoint group)

Powershell responds with this: Set-SPOSiteGroup: The user newgroup2 was not found.

What is wrong with my command? I am sure newgroup2 exists, and i am able to make it the owner of newgroup using the sharepoint interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following powershell code to set the group owner,

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell

#Get the SPWeb
$web = Get-SPWeb http://url_to_web

#Get the Group
$group1 = $web.SiteGroups["newgroup"]

#Get the Group 
$group2 = $web.SiteGroups["newgroup2"]

#Assign Group as the owner
$group1.Owner = $group2

#Update the Group
$group1.Update()

Remove-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to set an AD-group as an owner, but you can set a SharePoint group as owner as a workaround.

## Steps

1. Create a new SharePoint group, add the Security group as a member.
2. Set the newly created SharePoint group as the owner of your existing SharePoint group

Reference: [Set group owner using powershell](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/t/197309.aspx)